# Adding JSeparator to a DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to add some JSeparators to a JList. I am using a DefaultListModel, and when I try:

```
((DefaultListModel)myListModel).addElement(new JSeparator());
```

I'm getting this written into the JList instead of the separator when I execute:

javax.swing.JSeparator[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@962d513,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,orientation=HORIZONTAL]

Comment: sigh ... you still don't understand how the rendering mechanism works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

little bit complicated in the renderer but possible, since example for `JComboBox` but with `ListCellRenderer`

[image]

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BlockComboBoxExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final String SEPARATOR = "SEPARATOR";

    public BlockComboBoxExample() {
        super("Block ComboBox Example");
        String[][] str = {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"1", "2", "3"}, {"abc", "def", "ghi"}};
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(makeVectorData(str));
        combo.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());
        combo.addActionListener(new BlockComboListener(combo));
        combo.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(combo);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private Vector<String> makeVectorData(String[][] str) {
        boolean needSeparator = false;
        Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (needSeparator) {
                data.addElement(SEPARATOR);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
                data.addElement(str[i][j]);
                needSeparator = true;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                //UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Panel.background", Color.white);
                //UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.contentMargins", new InsetsUIResource(0,0,0,0));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        BlockComboBoxExample frame = new BlockComboBoxExample();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    private class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JSeparator separator;

        public ComboBoxRenderer() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
            separator = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
            if (SEPARATOR.equals(str)) {
                return separator;
            }
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                setBackground(list.getBackground());
                setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }
            setFont(list.getFont());
            setText(str);
            return this;
        }
    }

    private class BlockComboListener implements ActionListener {

        private JComboBox combo;
        private Object currentItem;

        BlockComboListener(JComboBox combo) {
            this.combo = combo;
            combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
            currentItem = combo.getSelectedItem();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String tempItem = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
            if (SEPARATOR.equals(tempItem)) {
                combo.setSelectedItem(currentItem);
            } else {
                currentItem = tempItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work, but using this renderer I'm losing the current Look&Feel colors for background, foreground and selections. I'm using Nimbus. If I try to put manually the colors into the if(selected), the only one which isn't working is setBackground for selection. Why is that?

Comment: That output is exactly what I want, but the dark blue selection color is white since I added the renderer. Have you edited the code for that? Because I don't find what's different from before

Comment: in your code must be setted something wrong beacuse I only to added change for Look and Feel, nothing else, I updated my code

Comment: It only works if I use the setOpaque(true). Sounds strange for me, but well, works anyway. Thanks!

Comment: hmmmm I use only jdk 1.6_022, best for me SwingWorker, Nimbus, Substance, JTable and I can't see any lack with usage WildCards

Comment: Holy crap I cringe every time I see this recommendation to this question. 
 
Don't do this. This is a bad answer. Reason being is that you can never have an element that is literally called 'SEPARATOR'. The 'value' argument to getListCellRendererComponent is an Object. You should have a reference to a static instantiation of JSeparator in the JList itself and instead of 'if (SEPARATOR.equals(str))' it should be 'if (value instanceof JComponent) return (JComponent)value'.

Comment: @searchengine27 you never to put JComponents to the XxxModel, then you never ever to need to test for instanceof nor inside the XxxRenderer, then String property is direct way, without side effect to XxxModel_to_view (quite intensive and can be very hard paints by XxxRenderer)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the DefaultListModel into a JList, and add a custom cell renderer to the JList.

```
class MyListCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer{

   final JLabel jlblCell = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.LEFT);
   Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1);

   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList jList, Object value, 
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    jlblCell.setOpaque(true);

    if (isSelected) {
        jlblCell.setForeground(jList.getSelectionForeground());
        jlblCell.setBackground(jList.getSelectionBackground());
        jlblCell.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    } else {
        jlblCell.setForeground(jList.getForeground());
        jlblCell.setBackground(jList.getBackground());
    }
    jlblCell.setText(value.toString());
    jlblCell.setBorder(lineBorder);
    return jlblCell;
   }
  }

    def renderer = new MyListCellRenderer();
    def listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    def list = new JList(listModel);
    .
    .
    .
 def dialog = new JDialog(ui.frame);
 dialog.add(new JScrollPane(list));
```

The above is a groovy code.
[image]